# Is this subset also a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group in which, for some integer $n > 1$, $\ (ab)^n = a^n b^n$ for all $a$, $b \in G$. Let $G^{(n-1)} \colon = \{ x^{n-1} \ | \ x \in G \}$. Is $G^{(n-1)}$ a subgroup of $G$? I know that, once we have demonstrated it to be a subgroup, then it is a normal subgroup.

Furthermore, I also know that the subset $G^{(n)} \colon= \{x^n \ | \ x \in G \}$ is a subgroup (rather a normal subgroup) of $G$.

Comment: Look up the article "n-Abelian group" by J. Alperin

Comment: $$g^{-1}x^ng=\left(g^{-1}xg\right)^n\implies G^{(n)}\lhd G$$ ...as long as it is a subgroup, of course.

Comment: I've also managed to find the answer to my own question. Yes, it is a subgroup. To demonstrate this, we note that $(ab)^n = a^n b^n$ implies $(ba)^{n-1} = a^{n-1}b^{n-1}$, which gives us the closure; and the inverse of $a^{n-1}$ is $a^{1-n} = (a^{-1})^{n-1}$.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud You should write your comment as an answer.

Comment: user1729, is it any necessary?

Comment: Geoff Robinson, can you please oblige me by giving the direct link to the article by J. Alperin?

Comment: J. L. Alperin (1969). A classification of n-abelian groups. *Canad. J. Math.* 21, 1238-1244; http://cms.math.ca/10.4153/CJM-1969-136-1

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud Yes, as it means that the answer will no longer appear as "unanswered", and as it will be useful to others.